# can there be two different columns of type link in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

If so how do we handle cellcontentclick event of each separately?  I am adding columns dynamically. Heres my code:-
`dataGridViewShow.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Date", DataPropertyName = "Date", CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() });`

```
DataGridViewLinkColumn toComputer = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
        toComputer.HeaderText = "Status";
        toComputer.Name = "link1";
        toComputer.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
        toComputer.Text = "Save to File";
        toComputer.ActiveLinkColor = Color.White;
        toComputer.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
        toComputer.TrackVisitedState = true;
        toComputer.VisitedLinkColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridViewShow.Columns.Add(toComputer);
        dataGridViewShow.CellContentClick += (SaveFileType_click);  

DataGridViewLinkColumn toNet = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
        toLinx.HeaderText = " ";
        toLinx.Name = "link2";
        toLinx.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
        toLinx.Text = "Send to Net";
        toLinx.ActiveLinkColor = Color.White;
        toLinx.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
        toLinx.TrackVisitedState = true;
        toLinx.VisitedLinkColor = Color.Green;            
        dataGridViewShow.Columns.Add(toNet);
        dataGridViewShow.CellContentClick += ("Don't know how this gets handled");
```

The above code does display two different columns of link type, however I can't figure out how do I handle each event separately?

```
private void SaveFileType_click(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedRow = e.RowIndex;

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            //some code goes here
        }if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && (string)dataGridViewShow[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != "Complete")
        {
            //some code goes here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't handle the events separately. You need to handle the [`OnCellClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.oncellclick%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or the [`CellContentClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx) event. Then using the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` object `e`, you can get the column and row that was clicked. Based upon which cell was selected you handle the event differently

```
public void dataGridView1_OnCellClick(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == YourLinkColumnIndexA)
        //some code goes here.
    else if (e.ColumnIndex == YourLinkColumnIndexB)
        //some code goes here.
}
```

So you wire up the event in code as you have done, but only *once*.

I hope this helps.